# How to avoid querying multiple times in serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have a model `story.rb` with field `product_ids`. it is a `Array`of ids.
in `story_controller` `show` action I have to return a `story` with it's `products` and `stores`. I am returning response through `story_serializer`. like this

Note: `story` has no association with `store`

```
class StorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ----
  ----
 def products
    here my query for products using `product_ids`
 end

 def stores
    here is the problem
    to find stores, I have to find product's first and then find store's of that product. so again I am querying for products here.
 end

end
```

I have `product_ids` so i can easily returns all the related products of that `story`, but the problem is to return related `stores`. How can I return store's without querying for products again. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *memoization*:

```
def products
  @products ||= begin
    some code 
    more code
   end
end
```

or if it is just a short piece of code

```
def products
  @products ||= some code
end
```

Comment: `@products` returning same values for next new request's too. how can i restrict it any idea?? @pascal betz

Comment: what do you mean by "request"? HTTP Request? Or just "method call".

Comment: `HTTP` request. sent by `curl`

Comment: Well, if state of instance variables are kept across requests, then something is rotten. Are you storing the serializer somehow?